# Show menu when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

i have the following menu:

```
<div id ="navigation-menu">
    <div id ="squaremenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a class ="homemenu" href="#Home" data-menuanchor="#Home"><img id ="homemenu" src="homemenu.bmp" height="30" width="30" /><span id="spanhome">Home</span></a></li>
            <li><a class="imprimir" href="#Servicios" data-menuanchor="#Servicios"><img id ="imprimir" src="imprimir.bmp" height="30" width="30" /><span id="spanimprimir">Imprimir</span></a></li>
            <li><a class="contacto" href="#Contacto" data-menuanchor="#Contacto"><img id="contacto" src="contacto.bmp" height="30" width="30" /><span id="spancontacto">Contacto</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

styled with css.

http://jsfiddle.net/t86Vp/

I would like if it's possible to hide most of the menu to the left and unhide it everytime i click on the menu?
If it's possible anyone can give solution with javascript/css?

Thanks in advance.

Thanks for your fast answer, i know i may not have explained myself well because english is not my main language.

Edit: What i really want is show only a portion of the menu, and everytime i clic it, then show or hide the other portion.

Once again, thanks for your fast answers

And sorry if i cant make myself clear english is not my main language.

**Solution for the people with the same problem/idea: (menu that open or close every time you click it**

Thanks to @Sergio

http://jsfiddle.net/6xCEp/2/

Comment: Do you mean removing the current CSS hover animation?

Comment: You need to do this by JavaScript cause css doesn't have on click event.

Comment: No, i mean hidding the menu to the left, and then when i clic it, unhide it and show the full menu, then once again if i clic it, hide it again.

Todd Motto, can you tell me how please?

Comment: You can use javascript to change the class of <div id ="squaremenu"> on click, and remove :hover from and change the name of class

Comment: What i really want is show only a portion of the menu, and everytime i click it, then show or hide the other portion.

Thanks for your fast answer guys, i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
$('#squaremenu').on('click', function () {
    $(this).addClass('abrir');
});
```

CSS

```
/************
*   ADDED
*/
#squaremenu img {
    display:none;
}

#squaremenu.abrir {
    width:36px !important;
}
#squaremenu.abrir img {
    display:block;
}
/***********
* END 
*/

#squaremenu {
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    top:150px;
    display:block;
    margin: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    background:rgba(43,50,61,1);
    font-size: 1em;
    color:white;
    width:10px; /* CHANGED!! */
    height:120px;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6xCEp/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer bro, i appreciate it, but i think i didn't make myself clear. Thanks for your fast answer, i know i may not have explained myself well because english is not my main language.

What i really want is show only a portion of the menu, and everytime i clic it, then show or hide the other portion.

Once again, thanks for your fast answer

Comment: @JesusAlbertoMendozaReveron, I think tweaking sergio's answer to use toggleClass instead of add and remove should do the trick.

Comment: @Sergio yea is kinda like that, did you changed something else because i add this script to my html and it dosnt work.

Thanks for your answer

Comment: @JesusAlbertoMendozaReveron, will make a more clear version, 1 min

Comment: @JesusAlbertoMendozaReveron, check this version: http://jsfiddle.net/6xCEp/ - I made changes to CSS and marked them

Comment: @Sergio Yea that worked fine, another thing, I've created another class called ".cerrar", and edited the script to this one but isnt working, can you help me out wit it? $('#squaremenu').on('click', function () { if($(this).className == 'abrir') { $(this).addClass('cerrar'); } else if($(this).className == 'abrir'){ $(this).addClass('abrir'); } }); It's supposed to hide the menu when clicked again..

Comment: @JesusAlbertoMendozaReveron, then its better to use `.toggleClass()` : http://jsfiddle.net/6xCEp/1/

Comment: @Sergio it's my if sintax correct? $('#squaremenu').on('click', function () {
    if((this).className('menu')) {
    $(this).toggleClass('abrir');
    }
    else if((this).className('abrir')){
        $(this).toggleClass('cerrar');
       }
});
sorry for being annoying i've never used jquery before... :(

Comment: @JesusAlbertoMendozaReveron, you don't need `cerrar`, just toggle having `abrir` or not. Anyway, when you use `this` without jQuery, remove the `()`use just `this.className`

Comment: @Sergio already made it work, thanks for your help buddy i appreciate it

the correct way: var clase = $('#squaremenu').attr('class').split(' ');

$('#squaremenu').on('click', function () {
    if(clase == 'menu') {
    $(this).toggleClass('abrir');
    }
    else if(clase == 'abrir'){
        $(this).toggleClass('cerrar');
       }
});
in every click it will close or open :)

http://jsfiddle.net/6xCEp/2/

Comment: @JesusAlbertoMendozaReveron, great! Just to be sure, did you see this (click to open & close): http://jsfiddle.net/6xCEp/1/

Comment: @Sergio no i didn't :( sometimes i make it more complicated, hey it stopped working for some reason, i have the jqurey library loaded and all, it was working before :(

Answer (score 0):

You may need javascript for this. Include jquery in your page and try this

```
$("#squaremenu a").on("click", function(){
    var $this = $(this);    
    $this.find("span").toggleClass("menu-item-visible");
});
```

You may need to group all css styles that show that menu under one class, then toggle that class as shown above. In my example I used the class menu-item-visible

Let me know if you have any more questions on this or if it's not clear

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, i know i may not have explained myself well because english is not my main language.

What i really want is show only a portion of the menu, and everytime i click it, then show or hide the other portion.

Once again, thanks for your fast answer

Comment: I have eited my answer, hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer i appreciate it.